# Using a variable to pass grep pattern in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, design-patterns, grep, ifs

I am struggling with passing several grep patterns that are contained within a variable.   This is the code I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
GREP="$(which grep)"
GREP_MY_OPTIONS="-c"
for i in {-2..2}
do
  GREP_MY_OPTIONS+=" -e "$(date --date="$i day" +'%Y-%m-%d')
done
echo $GREP_MY_OPTIONS

IFS=$'\n'
MYARRAY=( $(${GREP} ${GREP_MY_OPTIONS} "/home/user/this path has spaces in it/"*"/abc.xyz" | ${GREP} -v :0$ ) )
```

This is what I wanted it to do:

- determine/define where grep is
- assign a variable (GREP_MY_OPTIONS) holding parameters I will pass to grep
- assign several patterns to GREP_MY_OPTIONS
- using grep and the patterns I have stored in $GREP_MY_OPTIONS search several files within a path that contains spaces and hold them in an array

When I use "echo $GREP_MY_OPTIONS" it is generating what I expected but when I run the script it fails with an error of:

**/bin/grep: invalid option -- ' '**

What am I doing wrong?  If the path does not have spaces in it everything seems to work fine so I think it is something to do with the IFS but I'm not sure.

Comment: Would you mind to do: `echo "${GREP} ${GREP_MY_OPTIONS} \"/home/user/this path has spaces in it/\"*\"/abc.xyz\" | ${GREP} -v :0$"`, to see what is the actual command that will be executed?

Comment: This produced:

/bin/grep -c -e 2013-01-17 -e 2013-01-18 -e 2013-01-19 -e 2013-01-20 -e 2013-01-21 -e 2013-01-22 -e 2013-01-23 -e 2013-01-24 -e 2013-01-25 "/home/user/this path has spaces in it/"*"/abc.xyz" | /bin/grep -v :0$

Comment: Stylistically, it is better to use upper-case variable names for environment variables, and use lower-case variable names for general use. There's then less SHOUTING in the script. Personally, I'd probably use something like `$opts` in place of `$GREP_MY_OPTIONS`; I also avoid the word 'my' in code whenever possible (which is actually most of the time), but that's my problem. Finally (for now), if I might need to use different `grep` programs, I usually use: `grep="${GREP:-grep}"` which allows an environment variable GREP to override the default. I did that with `date` when testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build the GREP_MY_OPTIONS as an array instead of as a simple string, you can get the original outline script to work sensibly:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/user/this path has spaces in it"
GREP="$(which grep)"
GREP_MY_OPTIONS=("-c")
j=1
for i in {-2..2}
do
    GREP_MY_OPTIONS[$((j++))]="-e"
    GREP_MY_OPTIONS[$((j++))]=$(date --date="$i day" +'%Y-%m-%d')
done

IFS=$'\n'
MYARRAY=( $(${GREP} "${GREP_MY_OPTIONS[@]}" "$path/"*"/abc.xyz" | ${GREP} -v :0$ ) )
```

I'm not clear why you use `GREP="$(which grep)"` since you will execute the same `grep` as if you wrote `grep` directly — unless, I suppose, you have some alias for `grep` (which is then the problem; don't alias `grep`).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to `grep` some content in a set of paths, you can do the following:

```
find <directory> -type f -print0 |
    grep "/home/user/this path has spaces in it/\"*\"/abc.xyz" |
    xargs -I {} grep <your_options> -f <patterns> {}
```

So that `<patterns>` is a file containing the patterns you want to search for in each file from `directory`.

Considering your answer, this shall do what you want:

```
find "/path\ with\ spaces/" -type f | xargs -I {} grep -H -c -e 2013-01-17 {}
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -H, --with-filename
          Print  the  file  name for each match.  This is the default when
          there is more than one file to search.
```

Since you want to insert the elements into an array, you can do the following:

```
IFS=$'\n'; array=( $(find "/path\ with\ spaces/" -type f -print0 |
    xargs -I {} grep -H -c -e 2013-01-17 "{}") )
```

And then use the values as:

```
echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
echo ${array[...]}
```

When using variables to pass the parameters, use `eval` to evaluate the entire line. Do the following:

```
parameters="-H -c"
eval "grep ${parameters} file"
```

Comment: Thank-you for your help Rubens, I am new to bash and grep and Linux in general.  I am trying to use your find command but I am struggling with the wildcard part of path, "find" is complaining of "no such file or directory".

Comment: @user1464409 You're very welcome; I've edited the command, so that you may filter the "paths" you want, considering only those that matches `/home/user/this path has spaces in it/"*"/abc.xyz`. See if that works. (Notice there is no actual linebreak, it's only there to avoid the scrollbar).

Comment: OK I have simplified this done to:

    find /path\ with\ spaces/ -type f | xargs -I {} grep -c -e 2013-01-17 {}

as the above was proving problematic and perhaps too complicated.  Now all I receive from the grep output is the number of matches.  I require the filename and the number of matches (which previously was reported as: filename:no_of_matches)

Comment: That should have been filename:count_number in my last comment.

Comment: It happens because you're giving the filepath to `grep`, so it some what of considers you already know to which file the count refers to; if you were giving a list, it, yes, would identify each file. You can, though, force the file name to be printed, as I've added on the edit.

Comment: It still seems to fail when I put the results into an array.  Each element in the array is the content before a space.

Comment: I get the error **bold/bin/grep: invalid option -- ' '** (as in my original question).  There is a space between the two ' marks in the error message.

Comment: @user1464409 Try to execute with the extra quotes I've added; anyway, you should not be having such problems if you can see the output by doing `find "/path\ with\ spaces/" -type f -print0 | xargs -I {} grep -H -c -e 2013-01-17 "{}"` -- mainly because `grep` would've already terminated it execution by the time of the array assignment.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply this time, but I took a few minutes away from this problem to try to clear my head.  First of all, thank-you again for all your help.  Second, your solution was nearly correct I just needed to add a -0 after xargs to deal with null inputs.  This now works fine when I hard code the pattern into the grep (eg grep -c -e 2013-01-17 filename), when I put MYPATTERN="-c -e 2013-01-17" and then use grep ${MYPATTERN} filename I get the error message **/bin/grep: invalid option -- ' '** again.

Comment: Ah, now I've got what you're complaining about; please, see my edit.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that at all.  Everything is sorted now.  You're a superstar!  Thank-you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing without making things complex:

First do a change directory in your script like following:

```
cd /home/user/this\ path\ has\ spaces\ in\ it/
$ pwd
/home/user/this path has spaces in it
```

**or**

```
$ cd "/home/user/this path has spaces in it/"
$ pwd
/home/user/this path has spaces in it
```

Then do what ever your want in your script.

```
$(${GREP} ${GREP_MY_OPTIONS} */abc.xyz)
```

**EDIT** :

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld stack1]$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 sgeorge eng 4096 Jan 19 06:05 test tesd
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld stack1]$ cat test\ tesd/file 
SUKU
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld stack1]$ grep SUKU */file
SUKU
```

**EDIT** :

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld stack1]$ find */* -print | xargs -I {} grep SUKU {}
SUKU
```

Comment: This seems to be a nice simple solution but what happens if the content returned by * also contains a space?

Comment: Thank-you as well for your help Suku.  I have tried implementing the "cd trick" you suggested but it also fails when I try to read the items out of MYARRAY (using for i in "${MYARRAY[@]}" do echo $i done).  When I echo out the contents it is again split at any spaces in the path.